# I have a SSIS package with .CSV file where

Tags: csv, ssis

My original data is like the below format:

```
col1             col2                              col3
"225537-009  |  CA, SAS LED, 2pin-2pin, 16", ENV |  1.95
```

I have a SSIS package which creates a .csv file but when the file is created I got the below kind of output in my file:

```
col1             col2                          col3    COL4
"225537-009  |  CA, SAS LED, 2pin-2pin, 16  |  ENV" | 1.95
```

Here, column delimiter is comma (`,`) and row delimiter is `"`.
Please suggest me what I need to change to get the original data.

Comment: Your post is a little garbled. The line of data does not have four leading spaces so StackOverflow is not formatted it as data.  It also includes commas, tabs, pipes and quotes in a confusing pattern.  Is your original data in a text file? Or some other structure?

Comment: Can you post more sample rows of the data that you are expecting to see as output?

Answer (score 0):

```
"225537-009 | CA, SAS LED, 2pin-2pin, 16", ENV | 1.95
```

This is somewhat confusing and/or invalid csv data, since the '*first field*' is quoted.

With `,` as separator this would be valid 2-field data:

`225537-009 | CA, SAS LED, 2pin-2pin, 16` and `ENV | 1.95`

With `|` as separator however, this would be invalid data since you have `, ENV` after the quote in the first field.

To fix, the double quotes should be escaped:

```
""225537-009 | CA, SAS LED, 2pin-2pin, 16"", ENV | 1.95
```

or even:

```
"""225537-009" | "CA, SAS LED, 2pin-2pin, 16"", ENV" | 1.95
```

or you should make sure the parser ignores the double quotes (but then you could have problems if any field contains a separator).

---

In case the first data are the (3) columns in your database, your csv writer should escape those double quotes, and output the following (with `,` as separator):

```
"""225537-009","CA, SAS LED, 2pin-2pin, 16"", ENV",1.95
```

Comment: Thanks for u r suggestion but we can't mess up with the data . I have to do some  change at ROW DELIMITER or COLUMN DELIMITER.  Please suggest me where I need to do this or else any where with in the package seeting?